# Root commands library

Tags: java, android, root

Right now I'm doing something like below to execute commands as root. But the whole thing seemed a bit manual so I googled a bit and found [roottools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/). Is that the recommended way to go or is there something better?

I want to be able to wait for commands to finish, read output and ret val's.

```
    public static void deleteSystemApp(Context context, String app)
    {
            final String MOUNT_RW = "mount -o remount,rw -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system; \n";
            final String MOUNT_RO = "mount -o remount,ro -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system; \n";
            final String RM_APP = "rm -rf " + app + "; \n";
            Process process;
            try
            {
                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                    os.writeBytes(MOUNT_RW);
                    Toast.makeText(context, RM_APP, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //os.writeBytes(RM_APP);
                    os.writeBytes(MOUNT_RO);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Update regarding the issue pointed out by Chris Stratton:
I was already urlencoding my app argument to ensure that nobody could pass something like "something; rm -rf /" or "something && rm -rf /" and wipe the device. But upon further consideration I completely dropped the idea about sanitizing arguments. And deleted that part of my code. Why?

1. Why would anyone want to do this to their own device?
2. If someone else is able to pass malicious arguments the device is already compromised.

Comment: `rm -rf` with an unchecked argument... *nothing* could possibly go wrong with that!  Please leave system programming to system programmers.

Comment: Well I do check the args. But you are right, a simple rm would do. Thanks.

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  Please do not try to do this.

Comment: Instead of being a smart ass could you perhaps enlighten me? I'm trying to make an app which allows you to remove bloat installed by OEM's.

Comment: Please leave that to people who know what they are doing, and build your skills developing normal, non-rule-breaking apps first.  Generally I don't agree with Google's refusal to provide a special user-blessed allowance for administrative apps, but when questions like this get posted, it becomes obvious why they chose to wall it off entirely.

Comment: I'm doing this as learning experience. I do plan to have my app reviewed and also release it as open source. I check file extensions. So only a limited number of files can be deleted. And encode special chars. What more do I need to be aware of? I want to learn :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37825/discussion-between-user672009-and-chris-stratton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original description:

> RootTools provides rooted developers a **standardized set of tools** for
>   use in the development of rooted applications. In the end, we will
>   accomplish this by providing developers with robust, easy-to-use
>   libraries that will drastically improve development times as well as
>   promote code reuse. This project is open to any proven developer that
>   feels they have something to contribute. By pitching in together we
>   can streamline our own processes, improve the effectiveness of our
>   apps, learn new techniques, and provide a better experience for our
>   users.

As you might understand **RootTools provides rooted developers a standardized set of tools for use in the development of rooted applications.** If you need non-standard tools right your own or modify the source code of RootTools. Usually this library will cover all your needs. I used it in few projects and was very happy about it.

Good luck.

Comment: And roottools is The "industry standard"?